# C++ thread still joinable after calling `join()`

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a piece of code that simulates the provider/consumer scenario where each provider and consumer is a thread. I've paired each consumer with a provider and the consumer will wait until its provider has finished (by calling `join()` on the provider thread) before executing. The code is as follows:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
const uint32_t num_pairs = 3;

auto provider = [&](uint32_t idx) {
  /* produce resources and put them in a global container */
};

auto consumer = [&](uint32_t idx) {
  /* consumer i is paired with provider (i-num_pairs) */
  uint32_t provider_idx = idx - num_pairs;
  threads[provider_idx].join();
  assert(threads[provider_idx].joinable() == false);

  /* access the resources */
};

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 2 * num_pairs; i++) {
  if (i < num_pairs) {
    /* 0, 1, 2 are providers */
    threads.emplace_back(provider, i);
  } else {
    /* 3, 4, 5 are consumers */
    threads.emplace_back(consumer, i);
  }
}

/* join the consumer threads later */
```

Most of the time it works fine but sometimes the assertion in `consumer` fails and the provider thread is still joinable after it has been joined. Is the implementation incorrect or is there something I am not aware of happening? Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we get an [mre]?  There is probably some sort of data race / UB going on that is not shown here.

Comment: Is it possible that the thread finishes executing at (or just before) the call to `join()`? From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable): *A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable.*

Comment: I'd guess that the consumer threads are starting and trying to access the `threads` vector whilst you're still populating it, as the vector is growing this will lead to dangling references and undefined behaviour

Comment: At the very least you appear to be making invalid assumptions about the order in which the providers and consumers will begin executing.

Comment: @AdrianMole no, after `join` `joinable` is always false https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yeah - I thought that but not sure if calling `join` on a completed thread constitutes UB.

Comment: @AdrianMole If multiple threads call `join` on a single thread at the same time, that is a data race and UB.  If, after `join` finishes and another thread calls `join` on the already joined thread, then an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Turns out when the vector of threads is expanding, accessing the threads inside causes the problem, as pointed out by @AlanBirtles. Allocating the space needed before creating threads seems to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector `threads` is growing as you push be threads into it, there's a good chance that some of the threads will start executing before you've finished adding all the threads. When the vectors capacity increases all iterators and references to it become invalid. This means that in `threads[provider_idx]` the returned reference could be invalidated between the return of the `[]` operator and the execution of the thread method. As this is undefined behaviour your observed misbehaviour of `join` and `joinable` isn't unexpected.

Reserving the size of the vector before creating the threads should fix the problem:

```
threads.reserve(2 * num_pairs);
```